# is there any high level GUI framework around for android sdk?

Tags: android, user-interface, sdk

I am rewriting an Android project, and I am stucked and sucked at making the GUI look like the way I wanted it too. It is easily achievable using HTML and CSS, I have done it with PhoneGap, CSS, HTML, JS, but it is kind of slow, so I want to do it native using Java.
(My background is C++ and some web programming stuff)

What I have been encountered so far is that the default GUI builder is not really pretty and I feel frustated almost every the time using it. And people recommend droiddraw in few other questions in Stackoverflow, but it also not resulting in pretty GUI as well.

What I want to have is some flexibility like HTML and CSS and from that I can execute native code.
I believe I can achieve GUIs like from the Facebook or Twitter client easily with HTML and CSS, but if i m going to do native using the SDK, I think I'm gonna need something like 1 month just to do the GUI.

So the questions would be:

1. Is there any GUI framework for Android SDK ? (More high level then the provided one)
2. How to render HTML/CSS that allows executing native code on interaction with its element.
3. Any suggestions welcome for any workflow.

And of course, Open Source solutions are preferable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some projects for some iphone like widgets in android. You can find them seperately mostly in github, so I have not even seen a complete higher level widget library yet. But you can give appcelerator a try. You are writing html,css,js and it compiles to native code. I personally did not used it. It is a free software. Some people are happy with it, and some are not. You should read some experiences before beginning development. http://www.appcelerator.com/

Comment: I have done a fair bit of research on few tools, i have tried appcelerator as well, i know that it does not use the webkit engine like phonegap does, but i did bumped to the how its licensing,

Comment: It seems have a Apache Public License v2, Proprietary software http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appcelerator_Titanium

Comment: i see. i ll have a look into it more later. now i remember why i did not pick this tool before.. it was because i wanted to make it available for blackberry device as well.